# Turning Sleeping Android Device on in BroadcastReceiver Class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcastreceiver class that starts a service. What I want to happen is when it starts the service it should also turn the device screen on. I haven't found a solution to implement. I tried extending the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` but it won't open the screen, rather it keeps the device on if it was already on. Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Have you tried taking a full wakelock?

Comment: @GabeSechan I've tried using a wakelock but it doesn't turn the screen on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this method

```
 public void turnScreenOn(Context context) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    wakeLock.release();
}
```

requires the permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Comment: Is there a more efficient way than using the wakelock?

Comment: if you want to turn on the screen in activity there is another way but you requirement is in the service so i think this is the only way